# Cross-device game saves

Tags: applications, cloud

My father loves the game Hay Day. I'm not exactly sure why but that isn't important.

He is on a Motorola Droid Ultra and the Ellipsis 7 tablet he recently got for free at Verizon for upgrading. Both running some version or another of Jelly Bean.

He doesn't want to transfer the data from his phone to his tablet, he wants to sync the games. He won't be playing them both at the same time. But I was just wondering, if that is a possibility.

Summing up, I guess I'm asking, if we can backup and download save data seamlessly. I'm not a programmer but I'm absolutely not a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Cross device save as explained by [Boggartfly](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/52475/boggartfly), is to be enabled by the game developer to use Google Play Services.

However, if the game does not support the feature, you can always sync the game's data saved in `/data` folder of Android across the devices. Unfortunately, that tends to be a root-only option, since reading/writing from/to `/data` folder requires root access.

If you are willing to root your device, [DataSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quintstoffers.DataSync.beta) allows syncing of data across devices over WiFi/Bluetooth/Google Drive/DropBox/NFC. It is easy to use once you have understood the mechanics of it.

This applies to all the applications on your devices not just to games.

Comment: There's a caveat about doing it this way with root: since you're going behind the game's back to do it, it may break the game completely. It might rely on data unique to the device (for example, for an anti-piracy measure), and replacing it with another device's data would stop the game working in that case.

Comment: @DanHulme, that is true. As of now, I have not encountered any problems, but I don't play much. It is a very realistic possibility. It is important to take a backup before messing with game data with Titanium Backup or any other backup solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure about that, but I think you can do the same if only the game supports it. The game has to make use of Google Play Services to do the same. Look for it in the game options. I'm a programmer so I know a bit. :)